# Is array order preserved when deserializing using json.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Will the order of the elements in an array property be maintained when I deserialize a json object to a c# object using then json.net library? For example:

```
public class MySonsThreeFootRadius
{
    public Boolean IsMessy { get; set; }
    public Toy[] ToysThrownOnFloor { get; set; }
}

public class Toy
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

{
    "IsMessy": true,
    "ToysThrownOnFloor": [
        { "Name": "Giraffe" },
        { "Name": "Ball" },
        { "Name": "Dad's phone" }
    ]
}
```

Does ToysThrownOnFloor retain the order Giraffe, Ball, and Dad's phone, or could it potentially be reordered?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on what collection you're using.

Any class implementing `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` can be serialized as a JSON array. Json.NET processes collection sequentally, that is, it will serialize array items in the order the collection returns them from `GetEnumerator` and will add items to the collection in the order they're deserialized from JSON file (using either `Add` method in case of mutable collections, and constructor with collection argument in case of immutable collections).

That means that if the collection preserves the order of items (`T[]`, `List<T>`, `Collection<T>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` etc.), the order will be preserved when serializing and deserializing. However, if a collection doesn't preserve the order of items (`HashSet<T>` etc.), the order will be lost.

The same logic applies to JSON objects. For example, the order will be lost when serializing `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, because this collection doesn't preserve the order of items.

Comment: This makes sense. I was pretty solid on the .net type mattering here but I still wasn't sure if the json.net deserialization was going to keep the order. I didn't want to make any assumptions about what was going on under the hood.

Comment: OK but what if I receive the deserialized Json object as an IEnumerable from an endpoint declaration in, let's say, my Asp.Net controller? I cannot be sure what Asp.Net did.

Comment: @jeancallisti You can check the source code. In general, you can relatively safely rely on arrays preserving order and shouldn't rely on the order of keys in an object.

Answer (score 9):

The [json spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) doesn't specifically state that the order should be preserved, rather it says:

> An array structure is a pair of square bracket tokens surrounding zero
>   or more values. The values are separated by commas. The order of the
>   values is significant.

The spec also states:

> JSON also provides support for ordered lists of values. All
>   programming languages will have some feature for representing such
>   lists, which can go by names like array, vector, or list.

And from the [json.net documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm), the deserializing example certainly alludes to the order being preserved:

```
string json = @"[
  {
    'Name': 'Product 1',
    'ExpiryDate': '2000-12-29T00:00Z',
    'Price': 99.95,
    'Sizes': null
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Product 2',
    'ExpiryDate': '2009-07-31T00:00Z',
    'Price': 12.50,
    'Sizes': null
  }
]";

List<Product> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(json);

Console.WriteLine(products.Count);
// 2

Product p1 = products[0];

Console.WriteLine(p1.Name);
// Product 1
```

Based on the spec and the json.net documentation, it would be safe to assume that the order is preserved.

Comment: From the spec you quote: **The order of the values is significant.** Doesn't that exactly mean that the order should be preserved?

Comment: @Falanwe, that's a good question. I think it is safe to assume the order is preserved based on the spec. Just depends on the implementation.

Comment: @Falanwe, see the recent edit where the spec does talk about an ordered list of values.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I like this answer, but could you please elaborate on how the json.net deserialization example alludes to the order being preserved? I was looking at the example in the docs and just wasn't seeing enough to go on, which is why I posted this question. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris, see the example code above with attention to the last 2 lines of code where `products[0]` results in the value of _Product 1_; and the json shows the first item to be Product 1 as well.