# Ordering of array elements in ASP.NET Core model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

Does the ASP.NET Core 3.1 model binder guarantee element order when binding to a collection?

For example, if I were to make the following POST request:

```
POST /api/endpoint
[
  1,
  3,
  2
]
```

To the following controller action:

```
[HttpPost("api/endpoint")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
  foreach (var id in ids)
  {
    // Do something with id
  }
  ...
}
```

Can the ordering of the elements be relied upon to always be `1 -> 3 -> 2`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954701/is-array-order-preserved-when-deserializing-using-json-net

Comment: Thanks @Achtung however I'm not using the Newtonsoft json serializer, I'm using System.Text.Json.

Comment: True, i would assume it works the same way when deserializing to an array but i do not know.

Comment: Glancing through the source code, it appears it can be expected. As it also uses, it appears, slices for larger objects. I say this as a comment because I didn't really spend enough time to ensure I read the source 100% accurately.